# Overlap element over other elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Currently on my page I have this layout

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title text-muted">UltimateWarrior15</h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">
            Adventurer card
        </h6>
    </div>
    <img data-src="holder.js/100px180/?text=Image">
    <div class="card-block">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="player-level-text" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Rank</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <label class="form-control text-muted">D</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It gives pretty simple result

[image]

But what I want to achieve is to move `rank` value from `label` formatted similar to input to some image asset or maybe just label with bigger font, that would overlap image like this

[image]

How to achieve this using `HTML` and `CSS`?

Sample
https://jsfiddle.net/46qnx1LL

Comment: Where are your styles? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @andreas I thought `bootstrap` styles would be recognizable. fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple negative margin, e.g. `margin-top: -75px;`. With setting the `border: none;` and `background: transparent;` only the font is visible. Now you only need to apply `text-align: right;` to the parent div and your letter is on the right side.

Here is an example:

```css
.card-block .col-form-label {
  display: none;
}
.card-block > .row > div {
  text-align: right;
}
.card-block .text-muted {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: -75px;
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.9.4/holder.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title text-muted">UltimateWarrior15</h4>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">
    Adventurer card
   </h6>
  </div>
  <img data-src="holder.js/100px180/?text=Image">
  <div class="card-block">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="player-level-text" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Rank</label>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <label class="form-control text-muted">D</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can apply the CSS `position:relative;` and then specify an offset such as `top:-50px;left:-20px;` which would shift the element 20 pixels to the left and 50 pixels up. You can also specify `right` and `bottom` and use positive or negative values.

If you find that the element is hidden underneath another element, then you can move it up to a higher layer by specifying the `z-index:`layer number`;` so that the element is positioned on the right layer.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2meva9x/1/)